# articles: health and fine dust

Tags: articles

Two questions regarding articles in this sentence:

(The) Fine dust is considered the worst pollutant threatening (the) health.

Is it grammatical to not put any articles in front of "health" and "Fine dust"?

Both of the words are not indicating any specific existing things. They are rather abstract
concepts. So I thought it would be right not to use any articles in front of both words.
but I wasn't sure if this was grammatical, especially with the word health..

I would appreciate any help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, you have it right.

Comment: You have a mistake in "Fine dust is considered the worst pollutants" (is - singular, pollutants - plural)